# changing the way the data is displayed when using a query

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a Query to filter another sheet, in my other sheet the data is kind of too complex and doesn't fit the date format if my document; So I'd like to remove some part of the format : (the part in the brackets)

```
2023-10-18[T12:14:57.687Z]
```

To do that, I thought about `LEN` but I can't figure out how to use this kind of formula in a query :

```
=QUERY('IMPORT QONTO DATA'!B2:B; "select * "; 1)
```

EDIT :

```
REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY('IMPORT QONTO DATA'!B2:B; "select *"; 1); "[0-9]+")
```

This is working, but doesn't iterate through my column. It only outputs B2. I have to extend B3, B4, etc to make it work, but in that case I can't filter...

Comment: Use `REGEXEXTRACT()` then `QUERY()`.

Comment: Why not, but how?

Comment: Can you show your desired output from input data?

Comment: Made an edit to my post :) I managed to step in. But actually, regexedit now blocks the query from expending.

Answer (score 1):

## Regular Expression

For the Regular Expression, I believe you want:

```
REGEXREPLACE(value, "\[.*?\]",)
```

This replaces everything within a starting and closing square brackets.

## Map Function

Make use of the [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en-GB) function.

```
=MAP(QUERY('IMPORT QONTO DATA'!B2:B; "select *"; 1); LAMBDA(val; REGEXREPLACE(val, "\[.*?\]",)))
```

It allows you to apply a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en-GB) function to every value in the returned range.  In this case, the REGEXREPLACE.

I have left the QUERY in, but it seems pointless at the moment.  This also works:

```
=MAP('IMPORT QONTO DATA'!B2:B; LAMBDA(val; REGEXREPLACE(val, "\[.*?\]",)))
```

I have used **;** separators as I assume your region specifies that.